# updating android app with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm doing a new version of my android app.

I only changed the versionCode (in the androidmanifest.xml) from 1.0 to 1.1. and now it gives me the error - Float types not allowed (at "versioneCode" with value "1.1").

Also if I rewrite 1.0, it does not work.

Quite baffling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`versionCode` should be only numbers only and not decimals. You can assign decimals for `versionName` which is displayed on PlayStore and in App details in the device.

For Example, if you have set `versionCode` as 1 in your first version it should be now 2.

set it as `versionCode="2"`

Comment: thank you. That's weird because the versione Code was 1.0, so I tried (after 1.1) with 2.0 and it gives me back the same error.
Now with only 2 it works.

Comment: @volso yes it only works with integer numbers and it is just to detect the version changes. Where are for user display, you can have decimals in versionName, I hope you got the point

Comment: yes, i got it.
It's weird that with 1.0 it works (at beginning), after you change it one time, you can't use again .0
That's all. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Version code is in integer numbers ie from 1,2....etc., and only version name is in decimals.